# Mailchimp API with NodeJS - add a member to list returns me "Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND"

Tags: node.js, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0

I'm working with Mailchimp API in NodeJS and fail to add a member to a list.

​

Here my snippet.js

```
var username = "&&";
var password = "&&-us&&";
var auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");
var url = "https://us-&&.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/[listId]/members";
var json = { "email_address":"test@ŧest.com", 
"status":"pending", 
"merge_fields":{ "FNAME" : "newuser", 
                 "LNAME" : "happy" }
            }
request({ url, json: json, method: 'POST', 
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 
                     'Authorization': 'apikey ' + password }
         }, function(err, res, body){
                 if(err){ 
                        return console.log("err:", err) 
                } 
                   console.log("connection succeed"); console.log("res: ", res) 
});
```

​
My console returns me :

​

> err: { Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND us-`&&.api.mailchimp.com
>   us-18.api.mailchimp.com:443
>
> at errnoException (dns.js:50:10)
>
> at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (dns.js:92:26)
>
> code: 'ENOTFOUND',
>
> errno: 'ENOTFOUND',
>
> syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
>
> hostname: 'us-&&.api.mailchimp.com',
>
> host: 'us-&&.api.mailchimp.com',
>
> port: 443 }

​I can't figure out what is wrong, if anybody has an hint, would be great.

Comment: Is us-&&.api.mailchimp.com valid url?

Comment: yes the real url is https://us-18.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/[listID]/members/

Comment: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND means client was not able to connect to given address, so for sure address above with && is wrong. That is why You got an error.

Comment: okay I have double checked my url and seems there was a typo there, now my console returns me "The requested resource could not be found." again it seems to me that all the fields are here but I go for a double checking

Comment: How do You pass listId parameter

Comment: like that: `https://us18.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/101113/members/`

Comment: I have also tried: `  uri,
    list_id,` following the documentation:  https://developer.mailchimp.com/documentation/mailchimp/reference/lists/members/

Comment: okay I had a bad listID. The list ID isn't the "id=foo" displayed in the adress bar..! but you can find it in the "List name and campaign defaults" tab, in the "setting" tab of the list's admin panel - doc here https://mailchimp.com/help/find-your-list-id/

Answer (score 3):

The valid url would be something like `https://serverName.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/listID`.

You need to replace the following two in the URL for it to work:

1. serverName - You have to generate your own specific API key which will look something like this: `#########################-us2`. You have to replace `serverName` with `us2` in the url in this case.
2. listID - You have to generate a specific list id on mailchimp from which you will get a listID which you will have to replace in the url, say `#######`.

So, the final URL will look something like this `https://us2.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/#######`.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem, but only in production. Everything worked fine in my development environment. I had forgotten to provide the required environment variables to my hosting provider.

As convention, I had 2 env vars. `MAILCHIMP_API_KEY` and `MAILCHIMP_SERVER_PREFIX`. NodeJS wasn't able to reach MailChimp's servers as a part of the URL was missing.